# Cobertura refuses to acknowledge code was covered

Tags: java, maven-2, code-coverage, cobertura

I am using the Maven (2) Cobertura plug-in to create reports on code coverage, and I have the following stub I am using in a method:

```
try {
    System.exit(0);
} catch (final SecurityException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
System.err.println("The program never exited!");
```

I know that I need to log the exception, etc, but that's not the point right now...Cobertura is refusing to acknowledge that the line after the stack trace is printed is covered.  That is, the line with the '}' before the `System.err.println` statement is not being shown as covered.  Before, the ending curly brace of the method was not being shown as covered, hence the `System.err` statement.  Any idea how I can convince cobertura's maven plugin that, since the `System.err.println` statement is covered, that ending brace has to have been covered?

Oh yeah, and I use a mock security manager to throw the security exception, since that's the easiest way I have found of making the test continue executing after the `System.exit` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Cobertura in a while (2005?), and saw this behavior back then. A similar problem exists with NCover for C# and curly braces following catch/finally blocks.

My suggestion would be to add to [this Cobertura bug report detailing a similar issue](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1474067&group_id=130558&atid=720015). Also, follow @tvanfosson's advice and realize not having coverage on a curly brace, which doesn't actually become anything in the JVM, is something you can ignore as 'noise'.

Comment: Thanks, I added my code example to the bug you listed.  Hopefully this bug will be fixed in the future, I didn't know it was a bug until you posted that link.  Just thought it was some configuration issue I missed!

Answer (score 9):

I would look at the coverage report.  Double check my tests.  Notice that the code really is getting covered and not worry about hitting 100%.  Code coverage is best used to find areas that you may have neglected to hit with your tests, but just focusing on getting 100% coverage as a goal is bad habit that can lead to you skipping tests that need to be written just because your tool shows 100%.  Use the tool for what it can do but don't fall into the trap of letting the tool define what you do.

Comment: I agree with your statement, however it is very annoying not being able to reach "perfect" code coverage when the code above and below a brace is covered.  These are tests that I'm making when the code is fresh, so there's not too much functionality yet.

Comment: Perfect coverage is a fallacy. You need to spend your time covering the complex code and not the getters and setters. Coverage is valuable only to the extent where it helps you achieve the goal you are paid for - delivering a product, not reports.

Comment: Perfect coverage is not the be-all end-all of metrics, certainly, but I disagree with your sentiment on testing getters and setters.  Many is the time that a getter or setter has been modified to have a side-effect that is undocumented, and it is hard to track down.  Killing a test solves this issue

Comment: >> "Many is the time that a getter or setter has been modified to have a side-effect that is undocumented, and it is hard to track down" 

Do you have any empirical data? My personal experience with medium size systems (100-1000 kloc) tells me that's not the case ...or maybe I'm just lucky :-)

Comment: You're just lucky :)  One of the particularlily nasty side-effects I've found is a getter which performs a O(n) computation on its output before returning...if a test case was created to explicitly test that O(n) functionality, it would have been easy to track down and eliminate.

Answer (score 4):

In the Java classfile format every method is annotated with a table mapping code offsets to line numbers. In this case, the closing brace does not produce any bytecode, hence it's not covered. This is an issue of imperfect correspondence between source and bytecode. It should be handled by the coverage tool, recognizing this line as non-code.

I know that [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) has similar issues. [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/) fares much better, but is commercial (not sure if it would handle this case also). If you use IDEA, you should try their [new coverage implementation](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+Coverage+Runner) - it's quite good and in active development.

Comment: I'll pass on anything not free ;)  As for my IDE, I use Eclipse quite extensively.  I would try out Emma but unfortunately it doesn't have a Maven 2 plugin that I'm aware of, so for now Cobertura's the best option that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and that Cobertura has already fixed this, but for completeness the missing coverage on the "}" was caused by the internal automatically "finally" block.

See your code as this:

```
try {
    System.exit(0);
} catch (final SecurityException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    // noop
}
```

Fortunately this is no longer happening for some versions.